# How to refresh parent component when child component returns

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack

I have a simple react-native application using `@react-navigation/native` for screen navigation.

The app consists of two components : `MyVideoList` and `MyVideo`

`MyVideoList` displays a list of videos, one of them is marked as `current` based on `lastViewed` field, and has a green background.

Let's say I have 4 videos :

```
Video 1
Video 2
Video 3
Video 4
```

and `Video1` is current. Now I tap `Video 2`, `Video 2` starts to play.

When `Video 2` finishes to play, I use `navigation.goBack` to go back to `MyVideoList`, at this moment, `Video 1` is still marked as current (green). I want to refresh `MyVideoList` so that `Video 2` (which has the most recent lastViewed field now) is marked green.

What I tried :

1. Use props to pass a callback from `MyVideoList` to `MyVideo`. but got error : `WARN  Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state.`
2. Use redux, with error : `ERROR  Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

What other approaches can I try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing a callback, pass the status parameter and update it in the details screen. Something like this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (route.params?.video) {
    // TODO video played
  }
}, [route.params?.video]);

...

navigation.navigate('MyVideo', { video: { id: 2, played: false } })
```

```
route.params.video.played = true
navigation.navigate({
  name: 'MyVideoList',
  params: route.params,
  merge: true,
});
```

See [Passing params to a previous screen](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen) for details.